# JS/HTML charge collection fees

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a charge collection fees tool in javascript and html. It will calculate collection costs. the I don't know why it's not working. I'm new in javascript so I don't know much of it.
Can someone help me with this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#vervaldatum").datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional["nl-NL"], {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  }));
  $("#vervaldatum").val(new Date().toLocaleDateString());

  $("#input").keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keyCode == 13) { //enter press
      $("#calculate").click();
    }
  });

  $("#calculate").on("click", function() {
    var n = parseFloat($("#input").val());
    if (n > 0) {
      var a = [];
      var r = 0;
      var k = c(n, 0, 1, a);
      var x = $("#vervaldatum").val();
      if (x.length > 0) {
        x = x.split("-");
        var z = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - new Date(x[2], x[1] - 1, x[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) - 1;
        if (z > 0) {
          r = ($("#typeklant").is(":checked") ? ct : ht);
          r = (((r / 364) * n) / 100) * z;
        }
      }
      var b = 0;
      if (!$("#btw").is(":checked")) {
        b = ((k * 1.21) - k);
      };
      $("#original").html("€ " + n.toFixed(2));
      $("#rente").html("€ " + r.toFixed(2));
      $("#costs").html("€ " + k.toFixed(2));
      $("#btwv").html("€ " + b.toFixed(2));
      $("#total").html("€ " + (k + n + b + r).toFixed(2));
      a.reverse();
      for (j = 0; j <= a.length - 1; j++) {
        var o = (v[a.length - j - 1] / 100) * p[a.length - j - 1];
        var i = (a[j] === "undefined" ? "0.00" : (a[j] > o ? o : a[j]));
        $("#schaal" + (j + 1)).html(i.toFixed(2));
      }
    }
  });
});
var v = [800000, 190000, 5000, 2500, 2500];
var p = [0.5, 1.0, 5.0, 10.00, 15.00];
var min = 40;
var max = 6675;
var ht = 8.15;
var ct = 3.00;

function c(b, n, s, a) {
  for (i = v.length - s; i >= 0; i--) {
    var w = (v[i] >= b ? b : (s == v.length ? b : b - v[i]));
    if (w >= 0) {
      w = (b != w ? v[i] + (((b - v[i - 1]) % w) % 1 == 0 ? 0 : b - v[i - 1]) : w);
      a[i] = (w / 100) * p[i];
      return c(b - w, n += a[i], s += 1, a);
    }
  }
  return (n < min ? min : (n > max ? max : n));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color: #efefef; width: 420px; border: 1px solid #13B9E9; padding: 10px;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="input">Factuur bedrag:</label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 150px;">&euro;
          <input id="input" style="border: 1px solid; border-color: #d5dbe0 !important; width: 92%;" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>BTW plichtig?</td>
        <td>
          <input id="btw" type="radio" name="btw" value="0" checked="checked" />Ja</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <input id="btw" type="radio" name="btw" value="1" />Nee</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vervaldatum factuur:</td>
        <td>
          <input id="vervaldatum" style="border: 1px solid; border-color: #d5dbe0 !important; width: 92%;" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>De debiteur is een</td>
        <td>
          <input id="typeklant" type="radio" name="typeklant" value="Consument" checked="checked" />Consument</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <input id="typeklant" type="radio" name="typeklant" value="Bedrijf" />Bedrijf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <input id="calculate" style="float: right; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; border-radius: 5px;" type="button" value="Berekenen" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div style="background-color: #efefef; width: 420px; border: 1px solid #13B9E9; padding: 10px;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="input">Oorspronkelijke factuur:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="original" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="costs">Incassokosten:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="costs" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="btwv">BTW 21%:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="btw" style="width: 200px;">
          <?php ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="rente">Rente:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="rente" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
          <div style="background-color: #666666; width: 100%; z-index: 999; height: 1px;">.</div>
        </td>
        <td>+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="total">Totale vordering:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="total" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div style="background-color: #efefef; width: 650px; border: 1px solid #13B9E9; padding: 10px;">
  <label>De tarieven van de Wet Incasso Kosten zijn:</label>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de eerste</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">&euro; 2.500,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">15 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal1" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">Min. &euro; 40,00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de volgende</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">&euro; 2.500,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">10 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal2" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de volgende</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">&euro; 5.000,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">5 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal3" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de volgende</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">euro; 190.000,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">&nbsp;1 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal4" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de volgende</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">&euro; 800,000,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">0,5 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal5" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">Max. &euro; 6675,00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate when you say 'Its not working' - Is it not working in the expected way or are you getting any error?

Comment: When I click on calculate it doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to provide the CSS and JavaScript for jQuery UI since you are using the `$.datepicker` plugin.

Next, you created a variable called `keycode`, but you use it as `keyCode`. Case matters in JavaScript.

```
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

if (keyCode == 13) {
    $("#calculate").click();
}
```

After those fixes, your code should work fine.

## Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#vervaldatum").datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional["nl-NL"], {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  }));
  $("#vervaldatum").val(new Date().toLocaleDateString());

  $("#input").keypress(function(event) {
    var keyCode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keyCode == 13) { //enter press
      $("#calculate").click();
    }
  });

  $("#calculate").on("click", function() {
    var n = parseFloat($("#input").val());
    if (n > 0) {
      var a = [];
      var r = 0;
      var k = c(n, 0, 1, a);
      var x = $("#vervaldatum").val();
      if (x.length > 0) {
        x = x.split("-");
        var z = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - new Date(x[2], x[1] - 1, x[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) - 1;
        if (z > 0) {
          r = ($("#typeklant").is(":checked") ? ct : ht);
          r = (((r / 364) * n) / 100) * z;
        }
      }
      var b = 0;
      if (!$("#btw").is(":checked")) {
        b = ((k * 1.21) - k);
      };
      $("#original").html("€ " + n.toFixed(2));
      $("#rente").html("€ " + r.toFixed(2));
      $("#costs").html("€ " + k.toFixed(2));
      $("#btwv").html("€ " + b.toFixed(2));
      $("#total").html("€ " + (k + n + b + r).toFixed(2));
      a.reverse();
      for (j = 0; j <= a.length - 1; j++) {
        var o = (v[a.length - j - 1] / 100) * p[a.length - j - 1];
        var i = (a[j] === "undefined" ? "0.00" : (a[j] > o ? o : a[j]));
        $("#schaal" + (j + 1)).html(i.toFixed(2));
      }
    }
  });
});
var v = [800000, 190000, 5000, 2500, 2500];
var p = [0.5, 1.0, 5.0, 10.00, 15.00];
var min = 40;
var max = 6675;
var ht = 8.15;
var ct = 3.00;

function c(b, n, s, a) {
  for (i = v.length - s; i >= 0; i--) {
    var w = (v[i] >= b ? b : (s == v.length ? b : b - v[i]));
    if (w >= 0) {
      w = (b != w ? v[i] + (((b - v[i - 1]) % w) % 1 == 0 ? 0 : b - v[i - 1]) : w);
      a[i] = (w / 100) * p[i];
      return c(b - w, n += a[i], s += 1, a);
    }
  }
  return (n < min ? min : (n > max ? max : n));
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div style="background-color: #efefef; width: 420px; border: 1px solid #13B9E9; padding: 10px;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="input">Factuur bedrag:</label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 150px;">&euro;
          <input id="input" style="border: 1px solid; border-color: #d5dbe0 !important; width: 92%;" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>BTW plichtig?</td>
        <td>
          <input id="btw" type="radio" name="btw" value="0" checked="checked" />Ja</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <input id="btw" type="radio" name="btw" value="1" />Nee</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vervaldatum factuur:</td>
        <td>
          <input id="vervaldatum" style="border: 1px solid; border-color: #d5dbe0 !important; width: 92%;" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>De debiteur is een</td>
        <td>
          <input id="typeklant" type="radio" name="typeklant" value="Consument" checked="checked" />Consument</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <input id="typeklant" type="radio" name="typeklant" value="Bedrijf" />Bedrijf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <input id="calculate" style="float: right; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; border-radius: 5px;" type="button" value="Berekenen" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div style="background-color: #efefef; width: 420px; border: 1px solid #13B9E9; padding: 10px;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="input">Oorspronkelijke factuur:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="original" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="costs">Incassokosten:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="costs" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="btwv">BTW 21%:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="btw" style="width: 200px;">
          <?php ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="rente">Rente:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="rente" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
          <div style="background-color: #666666; width: 100%; z-index: 999; height: 1px;">.</div>
        </td>
        <td>+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 190px;">
          <label for="total">Totale vordering:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="total" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div style="background-color: #efefef; width: 650px; border: 1px solid #13B9E9; padding: 10px;">
  <label>De tarieven van de Wet Incasso Kosten zijn:</label>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de eerste</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">&euro; 2.500,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">15 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal1" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">Min. &euro; 40,00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de volgende</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">&euro; 2.500,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">10 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal2" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de volgende</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">&euro; 5.000,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">5 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal3" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de volgende</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">euro; 190.000,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">&nbsp;1 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal4" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Over de volgende</td>
        <td align="Right" width="100px">&euro; 800,000,00</td>
        <td align="right" width="70px">0,5 %</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">=</td>
        <td align="right" width="30px">&euro;</td>
        <td id="schaal5" align="right" width="70px">0.00</td>
        <td align="right" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="150px">Max. &euro; 6675,00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing what's not working it the BTW 21%. Do you know something for that?

Comment: Looks like you have a random `<?php ?>` tag in that table cell. Check your console for parsing errors.